# equivalent of OnSelect javascript hook in multi-select asp listbox

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a multi-select `<asp:listbox>` and a button.  I want to disable the button unless >= 1 item in the listbox is selected.  How can I do this client-side?  I can't find some sort of `OnSelect` callback, only `OnSelectedIndexChanged` which from googling seems complicated to use for this behavior, possibly impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use OnChange event, and count the selected items :

```
<script>function enableButton(opt) {
      var selected = new Array();
      var count = 0;
      for (var intLoop=0; intLoop < opt.length; intLoop++) {
         if (opt[intLoop].selected) {
            count++;
         }
      }
      if (count >= 1)
      {
       // disable button
      }
   }
</script>

<select id="list" style="font-size: 11px;"   
    onChange="enableButton(this.options);" MULTIPLE SIZE="5">
    <option value="0">Select...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT :** ASP:ListBox rendered to HTML as select as the code above. So all you need to do is to add the script at the onchange attribute :

```
myListBox.Attributes.Add("onchange", "enableButton(this.options);");
```

Comment: I'm using the declarative asp:listbox syntax.  Do additional attributes that aren't recognized by ASP fall through to the rendered html?

Comment: Almost all the client events are messing the server side events :) So they added some properties to some components like OnClientChange that refers to OnChange.

Answer (score 2):

This wouldn't be so hard to do using jQuery. Something along the lines of -

```
$("select#myListBox").change(function() {
   if ($("select#myListBox option:selected").length >= 1)
      $("input#myButton").attr("disabled", "true");
}
```

All hail the mighty jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

OnClick or OnChange for a selectbox is the same thing as a "OnSelect".

Comment: I don't think those attributes exist on <asp:ListBox> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4d7ktzs.aspx

Comment: Well, they do exist in HTML which is what the user will be seeing after all.